# How to count the number of appearances of a word in each line

Tags: bash, text, count, grep

I have a text file and I would like to count for each line the number of appearances of a given word for example if the word is "text" and the file is

```
abc text fff text text jjj
fff fff text ddd
eee rrr ttt yyy
```

I expect the output

```
3
1
0
```

How can I achieve this with bash?

Comment: How should `texttext` and `footextbar` be counted?

Comment: For my needs, I assume the appearances of the words are separated by a known delimiter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
while read line; do echo "$line" |tr ' ' '\n' |grep text -c ; done < file
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `awk`.

```
awk '{print gsub(/text/,"")}' file.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

```
while read line
do
echo $(grep -o "text" <<< "$line" | wc -l)
done < file
```